# Website not filling entire width of screen

Tags: css

I just noticed today that my site is suddenly not filling the width of the screen.

[link removed]

If you scroll to the right, you will see dead space from the top to the bottom.  I have tried adjusting the screen resolution, and double checking all css rules pertaining to page max-width, but I can't seem to find what is causing the issue.

**How can I get my main container to fill the width of the page?**

Comment: "SOLVED" should not be in the title of the question.

Comment: Hey Ben, if you change your title into a question that can help the community that would merit an upvote. For best results on this site try to phrase your question in a way where it can help others in the future. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your css, this should force your view to 100% while disabling horizontal scrolling.

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**edit:**

this worked in my web-inspector but I had to add **!important** to both settings. It looks like bootstrap is overriding your stylesheets. It's hard for me to tell because I am on my iMac and don't have access to my PC right now. Good Luck!

Comment: Dan, thank you!  That fixed it.  I tried the same code before, but didn't think to use the "!" override.  But I believe you're right about the Bootstrap override.  Thanks, again.  My day just got a fraction easier.  Lol.

Comment: Not a problem, just be careful with those !important overrides, if you lean on them too heavily it'll wind up frustrating you later.